# ORA: 00928 SELECT keyword missing

Tags: oracle

## code to delete duplicate rows

## getting a select keyword missing error . please help me solve it.

```
  With studentCTE As (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition BY RNO ORDER By NAME) as RowNumber 
      from student) 

   Delete from studentCTE 
    where RowNumber > 1; 

   select * from studentCTE;
```

Comment: Commont table expression has scope of one statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete from a table, you need to start with the word DELETE. You can choose what rows to delete by using a query, but every part of the query (including the WITH clause) has to be together after the DELETE.

```
delete from student where rowid in (
  with cte as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition BY RNO ORDER By NAME) as RowNumber,
      rowid as rid
    from student
  )
  select rid from cte
  where rownumber > 1
);
```